# C# DoubleAnimation Smoothness

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to fade out a `UIElement` using storyboards and a double animation, the element does indeed fade out but it seems to do it in 2 steps rather than a gradual change in its duration. It looks like it jumps from 1 to 0.5 to 0 with only 3 changes but i would like it to change the opacity a lot more smoother than this.

Here is my current code:

```
public void fadeout(UIElement target, int targetopac = 0, int fadetime = 1000)
{
    Storyboard FadeOut = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation Fade = new DoubleAnimation();
    Fade.From = target.Opacity;
    Fade.To = targetopac;
    Fade.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fadetime);
    FadeOut.Children.Add(Fade);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(Fade, target);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Fade, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.Opacity)"));
    FadeOut.Begin();
}
```

Edit: The code seems to work perfectly on 64-bit systems but any 32-bit system i try it on the jumps still occur

Comment: I think you will have to do something like [`Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(Fade, 30);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.setdesiredframerate?view=netframework-4.7.2). with `30` being the desired framerate.  I'm not that great with wpf animations, especially when done through code.  When I do use them, it's usually via XAML.

Comment: Yeah i gave that a shot but the issue still remains, i'm not too familiar with XAML so i was trying to stick with c# for it.

Comment: Are you burning the ui thread with some other code at the same time? Btw. You can just use an animation without a storyboard for single property animation like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the C# code you have is not working as intended but in case XAML code is useful to you here is an example in XAML doing the same. I feel XAML is clearer and more brief.
Here I bind the animation to trigger on mouse click on the element for example:

```
<Grid Background="Red" >
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="">
                    <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" AutoReverse="True" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

But you can of course attach it to any other event or invoke the storyboard from code behind by locating it using its resource key like this:

```
<Grid Background="Red" x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OpacityStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="00:00:01"
                             Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference Name=MyGrid}"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             AutoReverse="True" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Invoke like this:

```
(MyGrid.Resources["OpacityStoryboard"] as Storyboard).Begin();
```